# Change width of <Video>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code for posting video to View

It is in JS

Here is code

```
 stop.onclick = function () {
    record.disabled = false;
    stop.disabled = true;
    window.onbeforeunload = null; //Solve trouble with deleting video
    preview.src = '';

    fileName = Math.round(Math.random() * 99999999) + 99999999;
    console.log(fileName);
    if (!isFirefox) {
        recordAudio.stopRecording(function () {
            //PostBlob(recordAudio.getBlob(), 'audio', fileName + '.wav');
        });
    } else {
        recordAudio.stopRecording(function (url) {
            preview.src = url;
            //PostBlob(recordAudio.getBlob(), 'video', fileName + '.webm');
        });
    }

    if (!isFirefox) {
        recordVideo.stopRecording(function () {
            PostBlob(recordVideo.getBlob(), 'video', fileName + '.webm');
        });
    }
```

This code is posting video to container

```
 if (!isFirefox) {
        recordVideo.stopRecording(function () {
            PostBlob(recordVideo.getBlob(), 'video', fileName + '.webm');
        });
    }
```

I need to make video window width = 350

How I can do this?

Comment: The video width? As far as I can read from your code, your recording a video correct? Is it the size of the Video player/HTML element or the width of the recorded video?

Comment: I mean Video player, sorry @Webbanditten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if it's only one video element.

```js
var vid = document.querySelector('video');

vid.width = '350';
```

```html
<video id="vid1" class="vid" src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" controls></video>
```

Comment: Thank's so much dude!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding.